# Combination of two Languages in a arbitrary complexity class

Tags: complexity-theory

Given two unrelated languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ contained in some complexity class $C$. Is the language $L_x=L_0\times L_1= \{(x,y)|x\in L_0, y\in L_1\}$ always contained in $C$?

And if that is the case, can we just extend this recursively and create a single language $(L_{All})$ from all other languages contained in $C$ (even if the count of languages in $C$ is infinite)? Is the language $L_{All}$ always contained in $C$ as well?

Comment: You will have to explain what "extending this recursively" would mean - how would you extend recursively? Do you start from two languages $L_0,L_1$ and construct $L_2:=L_0\times L_1$, and then $L_3:=L_1\times L_2$, and so on with the recurrence formula of $L_{n+2}=L_n\times L_{n+1}$ ? Is this the process you have in your mind?

Comment: The answer depends on the class $C$.

Comment: @nirshahar yes. Exactly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i understand/agree. I was reffering to the english meaning. I guess I should have used 'arbitrary' or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the class $C$. Many classes will be closed under your operation, but some are not. For example, DCFL, the class of all deterministic context-free language, is not. To show this, we slightly adapt the counterexample in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7325/why-are-deterministic-pdas-not-closed-under-concatenation). Define
$$
L_A = \{ a^i b^j c^k : i \neq j \}; L_B = \{ a^i b^j c^k : j \neq k \}; L_1 = \{ ,w : w \in L_A \} \cup L_B; L_0 = \; ,^*
$$
The languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ are both DCFL. Let $L_x = L_0 \times L_1$ be their product. Suppose that $L_x$ were DCFL. Then so would $L_y = \{ w : (w) \in L_x \}$ be, since DCFL is closed under quotient. Since DCFL is closed under intersection with a regular language, $L_z = L_y \cap \, ,,(a+b+c)^*$ would be DCFL. Notice that $L_z = \, ,, (L_A \cup L_B)$. Again using closure under quotient, it would follow that $L_A \cup L_B$ is DCFL, but that is known to be false.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still trying to understand the counterexample. Assuming the class $C$ is the class i.e. $\Sigma_2^P$ in the second level of the polynomial hierarchy. Is that one closed under the above criteria?

Comment: You can ask as many questions as there are complexity classes. Some complexity classes are closed, since aren’t. There’s no general rule.

Comment: I understand. But for the specific case of $\Sigma_2^P$ any pointers how to figure it out?

Comment: Use the definition.